# Remove value from comma delimited string SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Suppose I have a comma delimited string (I know, it's better to normalize it, but it's not an option) and the records look like this (note the space after each comma):

```
11, 15, 17, 23
15, 34, 46, 69
15
27, 41, 29, 15
```

I need to remove '15' from all of the values that have it regardless of the position. As you can see, the number can be the only value, in the beginning, middle, at the very end of the string. After I'm done, I would like my records to look like this:

```
11, 17, 23
34, 46, 69

27, 41, 29
```

I know I can create 3-4 separate queries to handle all of the different cases, but would really like to have 1 query.

TIA,
-TS.

Comment: Yuck....just yuck. This is one of the major reasons why delimited data is a total mess to work with. You will need a string splitter to first separate the values into something usable. Then you will need to use STUFF and FOR XML to smash them back together into this denormalized nightmare.

Comment: Use a nested replace.  The innermost is `, 15,`.  You can figure out the rest.

Comment: Fix your data structure so you are not storing lists of numbers as strings.  That is the real solution to your problem.

Comment: @DanBracuk the inner one is the only one that is workable using replace. Anything else can return false positives. "15," or ", 15" are not going to work well here at all.

Comment: Yes guys, like I mentioned ... normalizing the data is not an option.

Comment: Not fixing that data structure requires you to follow the steps I listed in my first comment. There is no easy solution that can be done in a single query because of the data structure. You are stuck.

Comment: Alright @SeanLange I'll just use 3-4 separate queries then. Will probably be easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**If you are absolutely sure it's impossible to fix this terrible database design**, here is something you can do, using a [CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql), [`REPLACE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql), and [`STUFF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql)

First, create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions):

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE
(
    BadColumn varchar(100)
)

INSERT INTO @T VALUES
('11, 15, 17, 23'),
('15, 34, 46, 69'),
('15'),
('27, 41, 29, 15')
```

Then, the CTE: **Note** I'm adding the delimiter before and after the actual value.

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT REPLACE(', '+ BadColumn +', ', ', 15, ', ', ') As Without15
    FROM @T 
)
```

The query: (I've used select to show the results but you can use it to update as well)

```
SELECT ISNULL(
            STUFF(
                STUFF(Without15, 1, 2, ''), 
                LEN(Without15)-2, 2, '')
        , '') As StillBadButWithout15
FROM CTE
```

Results:

```
StillBadButWithout15
11, 17, 23
34, 46, 69

27, 41, 29
```

[See a live demo on rextester.](http://rextester.com/ZXV77677)

### Update

You can add the original column to the cte and simply update the cte directly:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT BadColumn, REPLACE(', '+ BadColumn +', ', ', 15, ', ', ') As Without15
    FROM @T 
)

UPDATE CTE
SET BadColumn = ISNULL(
                    STUFF(
                        STUFF(Without15, 1, 2, ''), 
                        LEN(Without15)-2, 2, '')
                , '')
```

[Here is the live demo for this.](http://rextester.com/XTP10591)

Comment: Hi @Zohar Peled. Your example does work properly, thanks for that! I'm not too familiar with common table expressions. What would the UPDATE statement look like in this case?

Comment: The common table expression is simply an alternative to a derived table. I've edited my answer to include an update statement version as well.

Comment: Perfect, worked like a charm! Would it be possible to run this whole block in a loop? Suppose I have couple of dozens of values to remove using the same exact technique and I want to avoid running this query as many times. I could create a temp-table with all the values that need to be deleted. Would I be able to loop through this temp table and run your code for each record in it?

Comment: You can create a stored procedure for it, but I would highly recommend normalizing the database. Even if it requires a lot of work on everything that's using this table it will be better then hacking your way through xomma delimited texts.

Comment: I cannot create SP or normalize the data. It's a commercial DB and I'm not going to change it. Besides, there are other functionalities that use this structure (comma delimited). Trust me, if I could do it I definitely would.

Comment: What would the query look like if I didn't have spaces after commas? If the comma delimited strings were like this:   11,15,17,23  
15,34,46,69  
15  
27,41,29,15

Comment: Sorry about the formatting, don't know how to insert line breaks in comments. What would the query look like if I didn't have spaces after commas? If the comma delimited strings were like this:   [11,15,17,23]
[15,34,46,69]
[15]
[27,41,29,15]

Comment: Basically the same, just without the spaces and use 1 instead of 2 in the stuff...

Comment: So I'm trying to do this in a loop and it's *sort of* working, but the query removes 1 value at a time. If a record has more than 1 value that needs to be removed, I'd need to run the query as many times. If I have a record with value '12,34,56,14,74' and need to remove '34', '74' and '14', it will only remove one of them at a time, so I'd have to run it 3 times for all of the values to be gone.

Comment: I'm a programmer, not a magician. I've shown you a workaround for a problem you refuse to fix. If you want to update your table for multiple values (that was not on the original question, BTW), you need a different workaround - namely, splitting the strings into tables, delete whatever rows you want, and re-create the strings back from the rows you have left. Either way it's going to have poor performance and you have no way to verify your data is stored correctly anyway.

Comment: No worries @Zohar. I realize I didn't ask the entire question initially. It's really a 1-time job that will not be likely re-ran again. I didn't come up with this design and it bothers me a lot too, but there's no way to create a new table and tie these together through some sort of ID. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL 2017 you can use the STRING_AGG function:

declare @valueToRemove varchar(2) = '15'

DECLARE @T AS TABLE (id int not null identity, BadColumn varchar(100))

INSERT INTO @T VALUES
('11, 15, 17, 23, 150'),
('15, 34, 46, 69'),
('15'),
('27, 41, 29, 15')

; with result as (
select id as orgId, STRING_AGG(result.res, ',') as newVal from (
select id, value as res from @T
cross apply string_split(BadColumn, ',') where trim(value) != @valueToRemove
) result group by id)

update @T set BadColumn = newVal from result where id = orgId

update @t set BadColumn = '' where trim(BadColumn) = @valueToRemove -- you wouldnt need this if the update was id specific

select * from @T

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what Zohar posted - I have:

```
select BadColumn, GoodColumn = 
  case
    when BadColumn like '15,%'   then substring(BadColumn,4,8000) 
    when BadColumn like '%,15,%' then replace(BadColumn,',15','')
    when badColumn like '%,15'   then substring(BadColumn,1,datalength(badColumn)-3)
    when badColumn = '15' then ''
   else BadColumn
end
from (select BadColumn=rtrim(ltrim(replace(badColumn,' ',''))) from @t) map;
```

A splitter is overkill for this but here's what that solution would look like:

```
with cleanT as (select BadColumn = replace(badColumn,' ','') from @T)
select t.badColumn , cleanString = isnull(stuff(stringAgg.item,1,1,''),'')
from cleanT t
cross apply
(
  select ','+[value]
  from cleanT tx
  cross apply string_split(t.BadColumn,',') 
  where t.BadColumn = tx.BadColumn
  and [value] <> '15'
  for xml path('')
) stringAgg(item);
```

Comment: I don't see the similarity... Side note: you could use `left` and `right` instead of `substring`.

Comment: Similar in that we're both handling the logic inline, not using a udf. I should have been clearer. I prefer substring over left/right because it's more portable, pretty much every rdbms uses it except for Oracle/PL-SQL which uses substr

Answer (score 0):

Three simple updates and I suspect more efficient than a single update

```
update table set col = REPLACE(col, ', 15', '');
update table set col = REPLACE(col, '15, ', '');
update table set col = null where col = 15;
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid this. I have few dozens values I need to remove and each will need 3 queries. Zohar's solution works perfect, but I need to find a way to run it in a loop.

Comment: You cannot run this is a loop?  If 3 is more efficient than 1 then 3 is more efficient than 1 in a loop.  And it is less code than the single update.

Comment: Your first update would change ',123, 1542' to '12342', and your second update statement would change '13415, 315' to '134315...